# Prevent AUTH for all but $mynetworks

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to prevent AUTH being both offered and/or reject any attempts to use it, when the connection is from somewhere outside of $mynetworks?

I only want people to be able to login when inside of our networks. Never allow login from the public internet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have two interfaces, one internal and one external, you could replace the

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

entry in your master.cf file to something like this:

```
<your_internal_IP address>:smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
127.0.0.1:smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

That is what I am currently doing with an outbound SMTP gateway for my mail server.  Then, Postfix is not even listening on the public facing IP address.